# Re-binding window event listeners after ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

In the following code snippet:

```
function pauseFooter() {

    window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll); // <- Doesn't work
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

    function onScroll(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}

pauseFooter();
```

I'm adding a listener to the scroll event (or wheel, etc) and after an ajax call, this function is being called again which adds another scroll event listener which gives me two console logs. I thought removing the listener would fix it but unfortunately not.

How can I remove the first event listener after an ajax call and re-bind it again?

Comment: Just don't call that function again. Re-binding `scroll` listener is useless

Comment: The code above is simplified over what is actually going on. On ajax load, all page modules are being initialized again so it's automatically being called. I could attach a global boolean to the window to check but was hoping for another, cleaner, approach.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. Listeners for entire page events such as `scroll` shoudn't be rebound.

Comment: But what if they're manipulating things on each page? Say sticky panels that fix to window, with varying panels on each page, one page may have two, the other six.

Comment: You load entire web pages via AJAX? If so, where do you output them, in iframes?

Comment: No, the entire site is ajax driven. All page content changes, only header and footer remain. But in the case specifically, what the scroll event does with the footer is dependant on the page content.

Comment: Anyway your approach is wrong. AJAX call only can set listeners for content added with this call. Scroll event listener **should not** be set with AJAX call, it should be set on page load along with your header/footer. If scroll event behaviour depends on the page content, you have to pass the needed info to scroll listener through some global variables or localStorage.